# Uncaught SoapFault exception: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ApplicationException

Tags: php, web-services, soapexception

Till yesterday my php code was working fine until today. I started to get this error. I did not change my code and having no idea how it happen.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ApplicationException: Error putting together artwork object from Lieberman's code and item number while generating on the fly image. ---> System.Exception: Publisher Code: "" is invalid at FulcrumGallery.Gallery.Lob.Artwork.PrivateGetByLiebermansNumber(String publisherCode, String publisherItemNumber) at FulcrumGallery.Gallery.Lob.Artwork.GetByLiebermansNumber(String publisherCode, String publisherItemNumber) at FulcrumGallery.Gallery.Lob.RootArtwork.ArtworkGetByLiebermansNumber(String publisherCode, String publisherItemNumber) at Metaverse.Chameleon.Web.Services.V2.LiebermansService.GetDataFeedImages(ProductIdentifier[] productIdentifiers) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Metaverse.Chameleon.Web.Services.V2.LiebermansService.GetDataFeedImages(ProductIdentifier[] productIdentifiers) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- in /home/wacti in /home/wactive/public_html/dev/poptart/orioleintellect_webservices/get_GetDataFeedImages.php on line 53
```

Any help would be great!